# Responsive email not rendering correctly on iPhone 5s device

Tags: iphone, responsive-design, email-templates, responsive-emails

I've customised an email template and seems to work fine in most devices and mail servers, but when it comes to the iphone 5s, the responsive layout (one column instead of two) is not triggered, and I don't know why.

I've tried with "shrink-to-fit:no", to fix some resizing issues, but this only makes the layout remain as the desktop version.

Here's my code for any help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

      <title></title>

          <style type="text/css">
         /* Client-specific Styles */
         div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
         #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */
         html{width: 100%; }
         body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
         /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */
         .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */

         .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */

         #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}

         img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}

         a img {border:none;}

         .image_fix {display:block;}

         p {margin: 0px 0px !important;}

         table td {border-collapse: collapse;}

         table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }

         a {color: #33b9ff;text-decoration: none;text-decoration:none!important;}





         /*STYLES*/
         table[class=full] { width: 100%; clear: both; }

         /* iPhone 5 Retina regardless of IOS version */
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {

    a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #c3cd2a; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }


         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #c3cd2a !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 260px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         img[class=col2img] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}




}               /*IPhone 5 only CSS here*/

         /*IPAD STYLES*/
             @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #c3cd2a; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }



          div, p, a, li, td { -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }

         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #c3cd2a !important;
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 440px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 420px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}
         img[class=col2img] {width: 440px!important;height:220px!important;}


         }
         /*IPHONE STYLES*/
         @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
         a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: none;
         color: #c3cd2a; /* or whatever your want */
         pointer-events: none;
         cursor: default;
         }


         .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {
         text-decoration: default;
         color: #c3cd2a !important; 
         pointer-events: auto;
         cursor: default;
         }
         table[class=devicewidth] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 260px!important;text-align:center!important;}
         img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}
         img[class=col2img] {width: 280px!important;height:140px!important;}


         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>  

<!-- Start of header -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  st-sortable="header">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" bgcolor="#c3cd2a" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" style="borde">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                     <!-- logo -->
                                    <table bgcolor="#c3cd2a" width="284" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="284" height="60" align="left">
                                                <div class="imgpop">
                                                   <a target="_blank" href="#">
                                                   <img src="cabecera3.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="210" height="37" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"/>
                                                   </a>
                                                </div>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of logo -->

                                 </td>
                                 <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; text-align:right; color:#ffffff; font-weight: bold; padding-right:15px"> Mail title

                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of Header -->
<!-- Start of seperator -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  st-sortable="seperator">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" height="0" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px;"></td>

                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of seperator --> 
<!-- start of Full text -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"  st-sortable="full-text">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>

                              <tr>
                                 <td>


                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner">
                                       <tbody>



                                          <!-- Title -->
                                          <tr>
                                            <td height="25px">
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>

                                          <tr>
                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 34px; font-weight:bold; color: #000000; text-align:center; line-height: 38px;">
                                                Titular amb unes quantas paraules per llegir

                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of Title -->
                                          <!-- spacing -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- End of spacing -->

                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                              <tr>
                                 <td height="20" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color:#fff">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>
                              <!-- Spacing -->
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of Full Text -->



<!-- Start of Left Image -->      
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" st-sortable="left-image" >
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" style="background-color:#fff">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <!-- Start of left column -->
                                    <table width="280" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <!-- image -->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="280" height="140" align="center" class="devicewidth">
                                                <img src="foto.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="280" height="140" style="display:block; border:none; outline:none; text-decoration:none;"/>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <!-- /image -->
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of left column -->
                                    <!-- spacing for mobile devices-->
                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobilespacing">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of for mobile devices-->
                                    <!-- start of right column -->
                                    <table width="280" align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth" >
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                <table width="300" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="devicewidth">
                                                   <tbody>

                                                      <!-- content -->
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; color: #666; text-align:left; line-height: 26px">
                                 <br/>&bull; xxxx xx xxxxxx x xxx
                                 <br/>&bull; xxxx xx xxxxxx x xxx
                                 <br/>&bull; xxxx xx xxxxxx x xxx<br/>

                                                         </td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <!-- end of content -->
                                                      <!-- Spacing -->
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <!-- /Spacing -->
<!-- START CENTERED BUTTON -->
<tr><td>                                                   
<center>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
          <tr>
            <td height="2" width="100%" style="font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px;">&nbsp;

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
          <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto;">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" bgcolor="#c3cd2a" width="150">
                    <a href="http://www.example.com" style="padding: 10px;width:200px;display: block;text-decoration: none;border:0;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 17px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #ffffff;background: #c3cd2a;line-height:17px;" class="button_link"><img src="info.jpg" alt="" width="18" height="18" />
                      M&eacute;s informaci&oacute;
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
          <tr>
            <td height="2" width="100%" style="font-size: 2px; line-height: 2px;">&nbsp;

            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</center>
</td></tr>
<!-- END CENTERED BUTTON -->



                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                             </td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of right column -->
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of Left Image -->      
<!-- Start of seperator -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" st-sortable="seperator">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td align="center" height="30" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; background-color:#FFF">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of seperator --> 
<!-- start of Full text -->
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" st-sortable="full-text">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>

            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" style="border: 2px #c3cd2a dashed ">
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                     <td width="100%">


                        <table bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth">


                           <tbody>

                              <tr>
                                 <td>
                                    <table width="560" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="devicewidthinner">
                                       <tbody>




                                          <!-- content -->
                                          <tr>

                                             <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; color: #666; text-align:left; line-height: 24px; padding-right:10px; padding-left:10px">

                                             <br/>
                                                El futur &eacute;s tant important com el passat i el present. Per aix&ograve;, ara &eacute;s el moment de comen&ccedil;ar a planificar el dem&agrave;.<br/><br/> 
                                                Si vols calcular la teva jubilaci&oacute; abans de accedir als regals exclusius, prova el nou simulador online de jubilaci&oacute;.<br/><br/> 
                                                Perqu&egrave; el temps passa m&eacute;s de pressa del que creus, pensa en la teva jubilaci&oacute;, pensa en els nostres plans.<br/><br/>


                                             </td>
                                          </tr>




                                                      <!-- Spacing -->
                                                      <tr>
                                                         <td width="100%" height="32px" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;"></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <!-- /Spacing -->

                                          <!-- End of content -->


                           </tbody>
                        </table>

<!-- End of Full Text -->


                                    <!-- spacing for mobile devices-->
                                    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobilespacing">
                                       <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                             <td width="100%" height="15" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">&nbsp;</td>
                                          </tr>
                                       </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <!-- end of for mobile devices-->


                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>



                     </td>
                  </tr>

               </tbody>






</table> 
<!-- End of Right Image -->








            <table width="600" align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="devicewidth" style="background-color:#FFF">
               <tbody>
               <!-- Spacing -->

                              <tr>
                                 <td width="600" height="50" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; background-color:#fff">&nbsp;</td>
                              </tr>

                              <!-- Spacing -->

                    <tr>
                    <td>
                     <!--inici icones-->
                                          <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="right" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="box-shadow: 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-moz-box-shadow:0 5px 15px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 5px 15px 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;
-khtml-box-shadow:0 5px 15spx 0 rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7) ;">
                                            <tbody style=" z-index:1">
                                            <tr><td height="10" colspan="6"></td></tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td width="15"></td>
                                                <td width="60" style="border-right:#5e5e5e 1px solid; text-align:center" ><img src="linkedin.jpg" width="35" alt="" height="35" /></td>
                                                <td width="60" style="border-right:#5e5e5e 1px solid; text-align:center"><img src="pinterest.jpg" width="35" alt="" height="35" /></td>
                                                <td width="60" style="border-right:#5e5e5e 1px solid; text-align:center"><img src="facebook.jpg" width="35" alt="" height="35" /></td>
                                                <td width="60" style="text-align:center"><img src="youtube.jpg" width="35" alt="" height="35" /> </td>
                                                <td width="15px"></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr><td height="10" colspan="6"></td></tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                          <!--fi de icones-->


                    </td>
                    </tr>

                   <!-- content -->


                                          <!--inici legal-->
                                          <tr>
                                             <td  bgcolor="#CCCCCC" style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; text-align:left; line-height: 16px; padding-left:25px; padding-right:25px">
                                            <br/> Consultar les bases legals.Li recordem que
Cr&egrave;dit Andorr&agrave;  mai no li demanar&agrave;, per correu electr&ograve;nic ni en formularis, dades confidencials com ara contrasenyes o n&uacute;meros secrets.<br/> 
                                             </td>
                                             </tr>
                                             <!--fi del legal-->
                                             <tr>
                                                <td height="25px">&nbsp;</td>
                                             </tr>

                                          <!-- End of content -->
               </tbody>
            </table>





   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: This code looks responsive in iPhone5 to me: https://www.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/display/summary/yGtP0lv9rFDLeMnyNHRICYtL4sBVOKahPNjsJ2CkRL9iG/shared

Comment: Thanks @GeoffPhillips for taking some time in testing it! The problem is in gmail for iphone 5 and iphone 5s, not in apple mail (the one you tested) so i'm afraid the problem remains.
I will keep on looking for a solution, but thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The responsive layout isn't triggered in the Gmail app because it doesn't allow media queries. If you want your email to be responsive in the Gmail app, you'll need to rebuild this is a fluid hybrid template.

Fluid hybrid design will allow you to build a template that is responsive without any media queries.

To learn more about fluid hybrid technique, try this blog: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a-fluid-hybrid-design-primer

Comment: Thanks again, I already know that gmail doesn't support mediaqueries, and this email is built with hybrid design (gmail for android is shown perfectly, for example). I've used a litmus bulletproof template, so apparently it would have to render OK in all devices and plattforms. I keep seraching for a solution.

Comment: Sorry. but this is not fluid hybrid. Fluid hybrid uses "ghost tables" which are hidden in MSO conditional code. I don't see any of that in your code. What I do see is fixed width tables (width="600") with the "deviceWidth" class on them. And you have media queries to control the size of those containers. That's media query-based design.

Comment: Ok, I see. I thought it was because I grabbed a bulletproof template from an email plattform (litmus) which renders correctly in gmail (before my modifications)
I appreciate your help knowledge, thanks again!

Comment: Update: Gmail will be supporting media queries very soon! https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design